# WordPress: How to deactivate Free ver. of plugin, before Pro will be activated?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hook

I develop plugin for WordPress, and it represented in two versions: Free and Pro. For licensing used Freemius.

I've got many messages in support like a: "I can't activate Pro plugin, due to error: `Cannot declare class A, because the name is already in use`".

So, users don't understand, that Free ver. need to be deactivated, before they activate Pro. Because it's look like user want to activate two plugins at same time.

I want to programmatically deactivate Free plugin, in process of activating Pro.

Of course, I tried to use [deactivate_plugins()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/deactivate_plugins/) functions, and hook it in `"register_activation_hook"`, but:

If I try to deactivate (for example Akismet) - it's working. I'm activate my plugin - Akismet is deactivating, but when I have activated my Free ver. of plugin, and tried to activate Pro - I getting same error - Cannot declare class ...

It's look like, that `register_activation_hook` fire too late, and it have no time to deactivate Free before.

I'm sure this problem is being solved, but I can't figure out how. Please, share your experience.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not found solution for deactivating plugin as I need, but I found another way:

In index file of my plugin:

```
$plugin_path = 'my_plugin/index.php';

if ( function_exists('is_plugin_active') && is_plugin_active($plugin_path)) {
    wp_die("Before activating Pro version, please, deactivate Free version. You can't activate it both.");
}
```

This "trick" allow me to avoid non-informative error for users (about redeclaration), and provide most useful message with instructions.